# Is it possible to field inject a Recycler View adapter with Dagger 2.11

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I've been using the new `dagger.android` injection functions and so far I've really been enjoying them.

However, I've run into this tiny issue whereby it seems impossible to field inject an adapter or basically any non-activity class i'm using.

I know that it would be easier to `@Inject` the constructor but since i'm passing in the data to my recyclerview through the constructor, this isn't an option for me.

This means that I have to call the component to inject my class.

With an `AppComponent` class that looks like this:

```
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder {
        abstract fun networkModule(networkModule: NetworkModule): Builder
    }

    fun inject(someClass SomeClass)

}
```

The generated `DaggerAppComponent` doesn't recognise a `.inject()` method after saying `DaggerAppComponent.builder().build()`

I'm obviously misunderstanding something about Dagger because this seems like the canonical way of injecting a class.

I suspect it's because I'm extending from `AndroidInjector` but if this is the case how would I inject a non-activity class. Because even if I made a `@Subcomponent` for just that class, it would still need to be called from `DaggerAppComponent`

Comment: The way I ended up getting around this was reading this article https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2017/11/11/dagger-rules-engagement.html and abandoning the assumption that I couldn't constructor inject the adapter. Of course I could but - like the article said - I was copying and pasting code that I didn't know the function of. After I added a public variable to the adapter that held the items, I could stop passing them through the constructor and then inject the needed dependencies without any fuss. This, however, also means having to inject the adapter into the view model.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of taste (and more flawless code design), but I do not think that you are doing this the right way.

What do you mean by "since i'm passing in the data to my recyclerview through the constructor"? You assign data to Adapter, not the recyclerview itself.

If you don't want to (but probably should) use MVP approach, goal of loading data from somewhere and then displaying it with RCV would look something like this:

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

   val recyclerView: RecyclerView by bind(R.id.recyclerview) // Custom view binding but whatever
   val adapter: TestAdapter? = null

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false)

       // Initialize
       recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
       adapter = TestAdapter(mutableListOf())
       recyclerView.adapter = adapter

       // Add data
       adapter.addItem(MyClass("Hey it's working"))

      return view
   }
}
```

As for android dagger, I don't actually find it any more useful than regular dagger. It makes things even more complicated.

I strongly do advise to use MVP for android. Here's a sample of mine, which eliminates any need to an activity / component to inject any dependencies at all, feel free to have a look [MVP sample](https://github.com/egorikem/Kotlin-Dagger2-MVP-RxJava)

Comment: Yes I meant passing the data to the constructor of my adapter, just like you are. `class Adapter(private val data: List<Data>) : RecyclerView.Adapter { //... }` So I can't `@Inject` that because I'm not injecting the `List<Data>`. And yeah I'm using MVVM, so that's the whole reason I want to inject my dependencies.

Comment: this is not answer to the question